# Unable to consume web service via web server

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I am trying to consume a Web Service via my ASP.NET website. I added a Web Reference and was able to consume the Web Service locally. Then I moved it to my Server and it fails with a message of "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the URL you are talking to isn't running your service. There is nothing on the other side at that IP address and port number.

Make sure you have deployed the service to where you think you've deployed it. Try accessing it through a web browser.

Comment: I am trying to consume an external web service through code on my website. I can access the .wsdl for the external web service through a web browser from my desktop as well as from my server, FWIW. Perhaps I should edit my question to clarify?

Comment: The WSDL is not the question. The question is the service you're trying to access. Try to access the URL of the service itself from the browser, and you'll find it's not there.

Comment: You are correct. However, I am confused as to why I am able to get a response when I try to access it from my local dev environment as well as from SoapUI?

Comment: @The: it could be any random networking issue, anti-virus, firewall, etc.

Comment: @John: So, the question becomes, how do I troubleshoot the network issue?

Comment: I created a Console Application to consume the service and it worked. Consuming it via a Console App is the end goal, so I'm good for now.

Comment: @The: interesting. Try running the console app from the same machine your web site is on (if you haven't already done so).

Comment: @The: I suspect a configuration issue. You're using a different URL from the console application than from the web site.

Comment: @John: I checked the URLs used by the console app and my web site and they are the same. I even ensured the casing was the same.

Comment: @The: it would appear that the network disagrees with you. Have you used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) yet to look at the network traffic in the two cases? Is the web application running under the same identity as the console application?

Answer (score -1):

Because you need to change the Web References to use your published ones (public Web Service URL).

Try change the web references and recompile your website

Comment: -1: no need to change web reference just to change the URL. Just set the Url property of the proxy. This is probably already done for you, and the Url is probably set in the config file.